# How to call this function to OnClick Event?

Tags: android

How to call this function to OnClick Event?
want to call onCreateOptionMenu by using onclick event or using button onclick event so kindly help me for this issue?

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);

      switch (mWhichRouteProvider){
     case OSRM: 
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_route_osrm).setChecked(true);
        break;
    case GRAPHHOPPER_FASTEST:
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_route_graphhopper_fastest).setChecked(true);
        break;
    case GRAPHHOPPER_BICYCLE:
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_route_graphhopper_bicycle).setChecked(true);
        break;
    case GRAPHHOPPER_PEDESTRIAN:
                       menu.findItem(R.id.menu_route_graphhopper_pedestrian).setChecked(true);
        break;
    case GOOGLE_FASTEST:
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_route_google).setChecked(true);
        break;
    }

    if (map.getTileProvider().getTileSource() == TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_tile_mapnik).setChecked(true);
    else if (map.getTileProvider().getTileSource() == TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM)
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_tile_mapquest_osm).setChecked(true);
    else if (map.getTileProvider().getTileSource() ==     MAPBOXSATELLITELABELLED)
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_tile_mapbox_satellite).setChecked(true);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following line in your onClick event

```
 openOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [invalidateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()). From the documentation

> Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The
> onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs
> to be displayed.

The method is available from api level 11.

Answer (score 0):

Just take all the code in onCreateOptionsMenu and put it in another function(doTheThing())

then you have

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    doTheThing(menu);
return true
}
```

then call do the thing in an onClickListener as well

Answer (score 0):

Why not use :

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuitem1: dosomefunction();
        break;
    }
```

To me this seems to be a better way